# How to sort higher to lower in Python

Tags: python, sorting, for-loop, terminal

Hi i need to **sort** a int value in **forloop** and i am running this on terminal, below is the code

```
match = myworld.objects.filter(series=1)
for i in match:
    print i.w
```

which results like

```
34
32
24
39
32
33
36
33
23
34
38
38
32
31
30
34
30
30
31
36
31
35
33
43
```

please tell me how can i sort them so that i can get  a **lower** to **higher** or higher to lower 
thanks

Comment: There is an entire [section](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html) in the documentation dedicated to sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for lower to higher

```
from operator import attrgetter
for i in sorted(match, key=attrgetter('w')):
```

for higher to lower

```
for i in sorted(match, key=attrgetter('w'), reverse=True):
```

If you don't need the objects, you can also just sort the attribute you are interested in

```
for i in sorted(x.w for x in match):
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in sorted(match, key=lambda x: x.w):
```

Sorted can take a key function to know by what to sort, in your case the w property of each item in match.